# parameter only in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I trying to achieve a URL of

```
http://www.dgcportal.com/Services
```

I am using this in my `RegisterRoutes` method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Categories",
                url: "{categoryName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

my action link is:

```
@Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "", "", new  { categoryName = category.Name }, null)
```

however, this gives me a url of `.../?categoryName=Services`

How can I achieve the desired effect? I can not have my controller be called Services as that is dynamically generated. I can see the obvious flaw in my route definition (how will it route to other controllers?) Is such a route not possible in MVC 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map route seems correct, but I think you should use RouteLink instead of ActionLink to generate your link:

```
@Html.RouteLink(category.Name, "Categories", new  { categoryName = category.Name })
```

Comment: This was closest so I'll gice you the answer, but it didn't end up working because it created an endless loop if categoryName was empty. I ended up mapping `Browse` to the url, which is acceptable enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Does this overload work?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx

Put controller and action name in and it should work I think.

Comment: No, that was the one I was using.